# Skrollr not animating without browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, skrollr

I've been playing around with a Skrollr demo but the animation on #slide-1 doesn't work unless I refresh the page first:

```
<section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg" data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -200px;" data-anchor-target="#slide-1">
        <div class="hsContainer">
            <div class="hsContent">
                    <h2>Scroll down...</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[Here is a link to the page](http://bitsofinternet.com/parallax). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Initialize skrollr when your preloader is done, or call `refresh` then.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a timeout function to refresh Skrollr.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
      var s = skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
      });

      skrollr.menu.init(s);
    }, 500);
```